# What are good practices for replacing hardcoded strings in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Let me start by saying that I'm a student, but close to the end of my education.

I'm developing an ASP.NET Core application as my final exams project and have a question regarding the use of hardcoded strings when referring to Controllers and Views.

An example is in a view of mine, I'm using @URL helper to create the URL for a specific view. This means I'm giving it two strings to look for

```
@Url.Action("UploadVideo", "Practitioner")
```

I have a habit of misspelling some things, and this makes it a pain in the *** to start the application only to be told the view is nonexistent and realize I've missed a letter.
My thought would have it controlled via enum types.

I would register an enum called Controllers

```
public enum Controllers
{
    AdminController,
    ClientController,
    HomeController,
    PractitionerController
}
```

And register an enum for every controller with its corresponding views.

```
public enum AdminControllerViews
{
    Admin,
    CreateNewPractitioner,
    UpdatePractitioner
}
```

Then I would use the enums to refer to everything, as the previous example would now be

```
@Url.Action(
   PractitionerControllerViews.UploadNewVideo.ToString(),
   Controllers.Practitioner.ToString()
)
```

Would this be bad code?
I believe this would be strongly typed code, and make it easier if I ever change a view's name. Instead of fumbling in all the views, I've used it in.

Cons to this would be

- unnessecary code
- Needing to "register" all new views in the enum before use

Comment: Instead of an enum, use a class with string constants. No need fot ToString then, but you still need to provide the constant

Comment: @HansKeﬆing I see what you mean with a static class only containing constants. In my example, I've divided it into views for each controller. Should i then create a class for each controller, and a class for the names of the controller, or would you put everything inside one, and use predefined Enumerables?

Comment: And what are the benefits of using a class instead of enums? Generally curious as our teachers never mentioned it, and all examples were used with strings. But I'll send him an email with my question and see his response.

Comment: A const may have a very slight speed benefit: the value will be included directly instead of a method call. Const (or enum) over "magic string" : compiler check against typos and (with the values spread over nice classes/enums) some intellisense help for the available values

Comment: In my little research time, I actually came across a solution that I think is what you mean. The post I found uses T4 templates (haven't worked with it). [Using_T4_Templates_to_Create_Strongly_Typed_View_Names](http://highoncoding.com/Articles/658_Using_T4_Templates_to_Create_Strongly_Typed_View_Names.aspx). But instead of having to write it myself, it checks for files and generates classes for the controllers and properties for the views.

Comment: I also create 3 static types with constants -- one for controllers, one for methods, one for parameter names. I do this for two reasons, one to avoid magic values in the client, and the second to separate public API naming from the code (let's say I would like to rename this and that after a while, normally it is not possible, but since I decorated every public piece I am 100% safe to do this).

Comment: @astrowalker I'm thinking that is the way I'm going too. We are early in the process, but already now it can be a hassle renaming a method. Since we have to go through everything and find the magic strings.

Answer (score 5):

Option 1:

There is a nuget library that implements a source generator

https://github.com/sleeuwen/UrlActionGenerator

It will scan your project for all controllers and actions, and generate strongly-typed extension methods to generate links.

Option 2:

Use `nameof` operator, like `Url.Action(nameof(Controller.Method), nameof(Controller))`;

Option 3:

Create custom extension method that uses lambda expressions and then parse them. `Url.Action<Controller>(c => c.Method())`. You will need to implement expression parser yourself.

Comment: I'll look into the options. 
Regarding option 1: I would like to use it outside of URL generation, ex. in methods returning RedirectToAction(method, controller).
Regarding option 2: I have the default HomeController. When using nameof(HomeController) it returns "HomeController" as expected. But ASP.NET only wants "Home". Either I would need some functionality to remove the Controller part, or rewrite custom routing.
Regarding option 3: If I want to use it outside of Url I would need an extension method for every single use case. 
But i appereciate your answer.

Comment: You should use the nameof command. No need to use an enum and keep that in sync. To map "HomeController" to "Home", simply write an extension method that replaces "Controller" with string.Empty

Comment: @citronas Yeah, that would be an easy solution. I'm split between using the nameof() method and the static classes. But thinking about it, I can't find a downside to using nameof, while classes would require maintaince.